# I restarted Apache and now I'm receiving the following errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

For some reason I cannot access my website anymore.

So, I tried to restart Apache and got the following errors:

```
rm: cannot remove /var/run/httpd.pid: Read-only file system.

rm: cannot remove /var/lock/subsys/httpd: Read-only file system.
```

Unfortunately, I haven't heard back yet from the hosting provider.

But what could I have actually done wrong that I am seeing this error now? And what does it even mean? Why's the file system only read-only? I haven't even logged in to the server recently, and the last time I checked my website was working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

`cat /proc/mounts` outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: yea, it's readonly.  Contact the service provider. You can try "mount /dev/VolGroup00/var /var -oremount,rw" to see if you can mount it read/write while waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `mount` - your filesystem has likely been remounted read-only due to errors.

This probably needs to be dealt with by the hosting provider.

**Edit**: My mistake - as the warning states, it doesn't have current info; what do you get from `cat /proc/mounts`?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply, Shane! I updated my answer, unfortunately I have no clue what that even means lol, do you have any idea what the reason could be why the filesystem has been remounted to read-only? I couldn't find anything specific on Google.

Comment: Again, updated. Thanks alot for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @krysis Looks like `/` and `/var` remounted themselves read-only; you could try to remount them read-write remotely, but if there's an issue with the filesystem (as there is likely to be) then they'll probably need an offline `fsck`; I'd recommend getting your hosting company involved to assist.

Comment: Will do. And thanks again for your help, Shane! I just really wonder what I did that this happened. I just hope they aren't charging too much for it. lol

Comment: @krysis If it's a VM, a temporary loss in connectivity to the storage may be the culprit; unfortunately, your logs probably aren't going anywhere other than `/var` (ie a remote syslog server) so there's not really any good way to take a look back.

Comment: So, I can't really tell if it was my fault, the hosting provider's fault or nobody's fault, right? I just don't want them charing me 75€/hr over this. Anyway, you were of enormous help, Shane. Thanks!

Comment: @krysis Check `/var/log`, but they will have stopped writing after it went read-only; I wouldn't count on them having useful info.